# Unable to traverse the gridview columns (Auto Generated)?

Tags: c#, gridview

I am trying to traverse the `gridview` columns in ASP.net web application, using the following code, However the code is not going inside the `foreach` loop.

```
// Code snippet to hide columns from a gridview named 'gvEmployees'
gvEmployees.DataSource = dvItems.ToTable();
gvEmployees.DataBind();
string name = "First Name"; //Column name supposed to hide
int index=-1;

foreach (DataColumn col in gvEmployees.Columns)
{
   if (col.ColumnName.ToLower().Trim() == name.ToLower().Trim())
   {
      // Getting the column index if find a match
      index= gvEmployees.Columns.IndexOf(col); 
      // Using the above index, hiding the column from the grid view.
      gvEmployees.Columns[index].Visible = false;
   }

}
```

I am trying to hide some columns from `gridview`.

Comment: What method are your codes in?

Comment: @ojlovecd It is a button_Click, On button click I am hiding the selected columns!!

Comment: are u using auto generated columns ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think u are trying to hide column based on column title so please try following code,

```
// Code snippet to hide columns from a gridview named 'gvEmployees'
gvEmployees.DataSource = dvItems.ToTable();
gvEmployees.DataBind();
string name = "First Name";// Column name supposed to hide
foreach (var col in gvEmployees.Columns)
{
  if (col.Text.ToLower().Trim() == name.ToLower().Trim())
  {
      // hiding the column from the grid view.
      col.Visible = false;
  }
}
```

### Update

you can also write following code:

```
string name = "First Name";// Column name supposed to hide
for (int i = 0; i < gvEmployees.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    if (gvEmployees.Columns[i].Text.ToLower().Trim() == name.ToLower().Trim())
    {
        gvEmployees.Columns[i].Visible = false;
    }
}
```

### Update when using auto generated columns (for single-column version),

You need to use the rowdatabound event and hide the cell (column) when the row is bound.

```
int index = 0;
bool hidden = false;
protected void gvEmployees_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(hidden)
    {
         e.Row.Cells[index].Visible =  false;
         return;
    }

    string name = "First Name";// Column name supposed to hide
    for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        if (e.Row.Cells[i].Text.ToLower().Trim() == name.ToLower().Trim())
        {
            e.Row.Cells[i].Visible = false;
            hidden = true;
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

### Update when using auto generated columns, (for multi-column version)

Using the rowdatabound event and hide the cell (column) when the row is bound.

```
List<int> indexes = new List<int>();
bool hidden = false;
List<string> names = new List<string>();
protected void gvEmployees_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(hidden)
    {
         foreach(int index in indexes)
         {
             e.Row.Cells[index].Visible =  false;
         }
    }

    // start - Column names supposed to hide
    // Building the list of column names to be hidden.
    names.Add("First Name");
    names.Add("Last Name");
    names.Add("Address");
    names.Add("ID");
    // end - Column names supposed to hide

    for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        if (names.Contains(e.Row.Cells[i].Text.ToLower().Trim())
        {
            e.Row.Cells[i].Visible = false;
            hidden = true;
            indexes.Add(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Harsh I am unable to use Title function - It tells there is no extension like Title !!

Comment: Nope count is returning 0 !! I have around 10 columns in the grid view!!

Comment: Thank you Harsh, However how will I compare my column names there?

Comment: Don't forgot to add the event to aspx gridview syntax.

Comment: Edit to put the correct answer first, and I'll upvote this one... :)

Comment: Hi @HarshBaid e.Rows I was unable to find, however e.Row was there, with a little change in the code I was able to hide the table column name, Code is - `string name = "First Name";// Column name supposed to hide
            for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                if (e.Row.Cells[i].Text.ToLower().Trim() == name.ToLower().Trim())
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[i].Visible = false;
                    hidden = true;
                }
            }` How ever it **only hides column name the column values are still visible!! ** what to do?

Comment: it did hide the column name, but that column values are still available !!

Comment: It should now, check pls.   :D

Comment: Hats off to you Harsh, You’ve made my day :)  Had it not been for your patience and diligence, I would not have thought of a solution like this. Thank you !!

Comment: Will this work for multiple columns also ? I meant if I have a group of check boxes or a check box list, from which all the check boxes that are not selected should be hided !! Thanks...

Comment: not directly possible, have to change the logic for that ..( Hint : have to use list instead of variables. i.e int -> List<int> ). I will update when I m on my PC. Best possible try implementing ur self first.

Comment: Or ask separate question based on this .

Comment: Thank you, Harsh for spending time on this !!

Answer (score 1):

Move these code to some other event like rowInitialize or PreRender or GridInitialize

```
string name = "First Name";// Column name supposed to hide
int index=-1;
foreach (DataColumn col in gvEmployees.Columns)
{
 if (col.ColumnName.ToLower().Trim() == name.ToLower().Trim())
 {
  col.Visible = false;
 }

}
```

Comment: Thank you HM. What I am really doing here is getting all the data into grid view, then using a dataview - RowFilter to get the rows according to a condition. My question is that after I put the above code under rowInitialize or PreRender or GridInitialize. The said columns will be hided!!. So for example if my ROWFILTER where condition having the hided column, will that throw an error ?

Comment: I don't think rowfilter will cause any exception with hidden column. You can try them out however.

Comment: Thank you HM, will do it and let you know!!

Comment: Hi Still I am unable to go inside foreach loop !!

Comment: Inside for loop or if condition? Debug and see what is the grid.Columns.Count?

Comment: its zero, However I got around 10 columns !!

Comment: Let me know on what event u r binding the datasource and hiding the column

Answer (score 1):

I think I might find out what was going wrong. You should not use DataColumn as the data type of the enumeration variable. Try this:

```
        string name = "First Name";// Column name supposed to hide
        for (int i = 0; i < gvEmployees.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            if (gvEmployees.Columns[i].HeaderText.ToLower().Trim() == name.ToLower().Trim())
            {
                gvEmployees.Columns[i].Visible = false;
            }

        }
```

Comment: No luck .. Still the code not going inside the foreach loop... I do have around 10 columns in the grid view!!

Comment: count is returning 0 !! I have around 10 columns in the grid view!!

Comment: @Jithu gvEmployees.AutoGenerateColumns equals true?

Comment: @Jithu Then you should put these codes into the handler of gvEmployees.DataBound

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that the columns are auto-generated (gvEmployees.AutoGenerateColumns == true).
Auto-generated columns are **not** in the Columns collection.

If you want this kind of control over your columns, I think you're going to need to generate them at design time. Can you use a DataSource object of any kind on your form, then hook it up to your GridView? That will generate columns in your designer file to match your data, rather than relying on AutoGenerateColumns to create the columns on DataBind(). Then the columns will be in the Columns collection.

Comment: you are right, Actually this gridview is taking values from three different views, So I cant finalize the column on design time!! Any workaround?

Comment: It sounds like a lot of work, but I think you need to add in all your columns at design time. How dynamic is your set of columns? You must have some maximum set of possible columns to display....?

Comment: The user is provided with a dropdownlist, where the user can select the desired view / column. So each time the table and the gridview column headers will be different!!